# Gamma function integral inequality

Tags: gamma-function

In appendix 1 of the [following paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08357.pdf), I found
\begin{align}
\int_s^\infty \exp(-\frac{1}{2}z^\beta)dz&<\frac{1}{\beta}2^{1/\beta}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)
\end{align}
however I can't figure out how they got that inequality. I tried writing out the gamma function as an integral and taking logs of both sides, but that got me nowhere.

Comment: The integral from zero gives precisely the RHS. So if $s>0$ it will be less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $u=\frac {z^\beta}2$, we have $dz= \frac 1 \beta 2^{\frac 1 \beta}u^{\frac 1 \beta  -1}du$
$$\int_s^\infty \exp(-\frac{1}{2}z^\beta)dz=\frac{2^{\frac 1 \beta}}{\beta}\int_{2^{\frac 1 \beta}s^{\frac 1\beta}}^{+\infty}e^{-u}u^{\frac 1 \beta  -1}du\leq \frac{2^{\frac 1 \beta}}{\beta}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u}u^{\frac 1 \beta  -1}du=\frac{2^{\frac 1 \beta}}{\beta}\Gamma\left(\frac 1 \beta\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out and posted it at almost the same time as you. I'll give you the points though since it's slightly different (even if the same idea).

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own!

Answer (score 0):

K. defaoite's comment is correct. In more detail, let $x=z^\beta/2$. Then
\begin{align}
z&=(2x)^{1/\beta}\\
dx&=\frac{\beta z^{\beta-1}}{2}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta}2^{1/\beta}x^{1/\beta-1}dz\\
dz&=\frac{2}{\beta z^{\beta-1}}dx
\end{align}
Doing integration by substitution one has that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-z^\beta/2)dz&=\int_0^\infty \exp(-x)\frac{1}{\beta}2^{1/\beta}x^{1/\beta-1}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta}2^{1/\beta}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)
\end{align}
which is the right hand side of the inequality. It then follows immediately.